# Sign alternating for $n$-th Eulerian polynomial at $x=-2$

Tags: polynomials, eulerian-numbers

What is the law of sign alternating for the $n$-th Eulerian polynomial evaluated at $x=-2$ ([A087674](http://oeis.org/A087674))?
I have some ideas, but need more (than 100 from related [A212846](http://oeis.org/A212846)) terms.

How and where can I calculate those signs for any $n$ and negative integer $x$?